# Render JSX from material-ui Button onClick

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jsx, tsx

I'm trying to render JSX when a material-ui button is clicked. I'm logging to the console when clicking but cannot see any of the JSX getting rendered.

```
interface TileProps {
    address?: string;
}

const renderDisplayer = (address: string) => {
    console.log('Rendering address', address!);
    if (typeof(address) == 'undefined' || address == '') {
        return(<div className='error'><li>No address found</li></div>)
    }
    return(<AddressDisplayer address={address} />)
}

const Tile = (props: TileProps) => {

    return(
        <div className='tile'>
            <ul>
                <li>{props.address}</li>
            </ul>
            <Button variant='contained' onClick={() => {renderDisplayer(props.address)}}>Display</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tile;
```

I can see the `console.log('Rendering address', address!);` running when the button is clicked, but the JSX isn't getting rendered.

Could this be because I'm using React functional components instead of class components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somehow unclear for me. If you want to render `<div className='error'><li>No address found</li></div>` based on `typeof(address) == 'undefined' || address == ''` condition, there is no need to click on the button and it's better to use  conditional rendering. For example:

```
{!props.address ? (
    <div className='error'><li>No address found</li></div>
) : (
    <AddressDisplayer address={props.address} />
)}
```

But if you want to render your address component by clicking on the button, you should define a state and set it true when clicking on the button. Like this:

```
const [shouldShowAddress, setShouldShowAddress] = useState(false);

{shouldShowAddress && (
    <>
        {!props.address ? (
            <div className="error">
                <li>No address found</li>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <AddressDisplayer address={props.address} />
        )}
    </>
)}

<Button
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() => {
        setShouldShowAddress(true)
    }}
>
    Display
</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please read about the **Life cycle** This not how react work onclick function
renderDisplayer is called and return JSX to onClick event you need to use **state**  here to render the component with ternary oprator renderDisplayer fuction do setState so DOM will update